# Removing duplicate code in python

Tags: python

Is there any library in python for duplicate code checker? I use python IDE and I am finding trouble refactoring my code. Are there any python library available which suggest duplicate code in the program/project?

Update: I found clone digger which as per its site,

We have tested Clone Digger on sources of several open-source projects. There are following drawbacks of the current report format:

> Differences are highlighted using diff algorithm. This way of
>   highlighting has nothing common with the abstract syntax tree based
>   algorithm of comparing sequences of statements for similarity.
>
> Class and function comments are taken into account during the
>   computation of similarity, but they are not presented in the output.
>   Therefore some clone pairs can look equal but marked as convergent.

Are there any tools better than this?

Comment: @Marcin: I would have been glad if you had provided something suggesting there are tons of those. I found some like clone digger but it doesn't seem promising to me.

Comment: Why doesn't it seem promising? Why haven't you mentioned any of the ones that you have found?

Comment: I have added it in question. Thanks you asked Marcin.

Comment: A snippet that detect duplicates: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578206-python-code-clone-detector-dont-repeat-yourself/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Pylint has a check for similar/duplicate code: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html#similarities-checker

Usage:

```
pylint --disable=all --enable=similarities src/yourcode/
```

Answer (score -16):

No there is not a duplicate code checker, as there is no way to easily distinguish whether it has repeated or not because depending on the program, there may be dependencies on the code that is "duplicated" and things may be overwritten, ect. . All in all, no, there is no duplicate code checker that i know of for python. However, the use of a better IDE that tracks variable usage may be helpful in this case. :)

Comment: It would be nice to have a library that can, just even suggest for the review.

Comment: What does this answer mean? Of course it is possible to check the text of python code for duplication, just like any other language.

Comment: @Marcin I know that you can check it, however, the OP is asking for a library to check it for him (atleast thats what i think hes trying to ask)

Comment: @PsychicOak There is no reason why you couldn't create such a tool for python. They exist for other languages.

Comment: I believe the answer means you'd have to roll your own duplicate code checker solution. Someone else probably hasn't done that yet.

Comment: @Marcin I know you can make your own, but OP is asking if there is one already made...

Comment: @PsychicOak Your answer strongly suggests that it is impossible: "there is no way to really distinguish whether it has repeated or not"

Comment: @Marcin Ok i will edit it now :)